# Count the number of "trues" for n booleans

Tags: java, count, boolean

```
Boolean a, b, c, d;
```

I would like to count the number of trues, each result should have its own associated action. Maybe something like:

```
int result = getResult(a, b, c, d);
switch (result) {
    case 0: break;
    case 1: break;
    case 2: break;
    case 3: break;
    default: break;
}
```

Any idea of how to write the `getResult` method body a pretty way? In the example, I used *only* four, but it should be extendable to a bigger number of booleans. Any other way to proceed is welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write a variadic method?

```
int getResult(boolean... vars) {
    int count = 0;
    for (boolean var : vars) {
        count += (var ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A better solution may be to use a BitSet which can be more efficient esp if you have many boolean values.

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet();
bs.set(1);
bs.set(4);
bs.set(9);
bs.set(16);
int setCount = bs.cardinality(); // 4
```

Instead of

```
boolean a, b, c, d;
```

you have BitSet which can have hundreds or millions of boolean values.

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet(4);
bs.set(0); // a
bs.set(1); // b
bs.set(2); // c
bs.set(3); // d
int setCount = bs.cardinality(); // 4
```

When you have a lot of booleans, this solution scales much better. i.e. each boolean uses one bit, however each `Boolean` is a reference and thus uses 32-bits or up to 32x as much memory.  Also `cardinality()` is implemented for you no matter how many bits/booleans you have.

Comment: Four years later: could you actually explain how this works? How would `getResult` be implemented with a `BitSet`? Looks interesting but I don't get how to use it...

Answer (score 1):

This is an oldie... but here's another way:

```
int count = Stream.of(b1, b2, b3).filter(b -> b).count();
```

Comment: I think either conditions are more expressive: 
`.filter(Boolean.TRUE::equals)` or `.filter(Boolean::parseValue)`. I would personally choose the first.